# How to retrieve data in a Fragment from Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch data from Firestore in a fragment that is using a `BottomNavigationBar`, in that fragment I want to display the User details like Name, Email id, etc.  But I have no idea how to use Firestore in a Fragment to retrieve data. Can anyone please help me with this

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment
{

public ProfileFragment()
{ }

FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
FirebaseFirestore firestore;
FirebaseUser user;
String userid;
EditText name, email, num;
```

Want to display the details in the EditTexts above

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    ImageButton setting = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.settings);

    View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    name = (EditText) view1.findViewById(R.id.nameed);


    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    userid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    final DocumentReference documentReference = firestore.collection("users").document(userid);
```

Tried using the piece of code below to  write data on the editext but got an error

```
   documentReference.addSnapshotListener((Executor) this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            name.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("nameed"));
        }
    });
```

This was the error
      E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: gmail.rishabh.myapplication, PID: 8597
    java.lang.ClassCastException: gmail.rishabh.myapplication.ProfileFragment cannot be cast to java.util.concurrent.Executor

```
     setting.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()  {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),settings.class);
            intent.putExtra("some","some data");
            startActivity(intent);
            getActivity().finish();

        }
    });
  return view;
}
```

}

Comment: I think there is no need of first parameter, remove this code--> (Executor) this,

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to pass an `Executor` object and an `EventListener` object to `addSnapshotListener()` method, it means that you are trying to use the following flavor of this method:

> [addSnapshotListener(Executor executor, EventListener listener)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#addSnapshotListener(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener%3Ccom.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot%3E))

This method helps you:

> Starts listening to the document referenced by this DocumentReference.

However, in the following line of code:

```
documentReference.addSnapshotListener((Executor) this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>()
```

You are trying to cast **this**, which actually represents your current activity to an `Executor`, which is no possible in Java. To solve this, you should use the other flavor:

> [addSnapshotListener(Activity activity, EventListener listener)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#addSnapshotListener(android.app.Activity,%20com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener%3Ccom.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot%3E))

In which you should pass as the first argument, an `Activity` object. So simply remove the cast:

```
documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple approach is

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document(userid);
docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        User user = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);
        name.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("nameed"));
    }
});
```